# Send data to EJS after calling initial res.render?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a variable to EJS a second time in my code and am running into trouble. Here is my code:

```
axios.get(yearURL)
    .then(function (res) {
        let data = res.data.MRData.SeasonTable.Seasons;
        years = data.map(d => d.season);
        app.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.render('index.ejs', { 
                years: years
            });
            app.post('/down', function(req, res) {
                let year = req.body;
                res.redirect('/');
                axios.get(`http://ergast.com/api/f1/${year.year}/drivers.json`)
                    .then(function (res) {
                        let data = res.data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers;
                        drivers = data.map(d => `${d.givenName} ${d.familyName}`);
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                res.render('index.ejs', {
                    drivers: drivers,
                    years: years
                });
```

Whenever I run this however, I receive an error that I cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. I've also read elsewhere that apparently you can not call res.render twice. So my question is, how can I pass another set of data to EJS after I have already called res.render once before?

Comment: Why have you defined app.post('/down') as nested route within app.get('/')?

Comment: Should it come after the get request but not inside it?

Comment: Yes, it should. But none of it should even be inside the axios call back...

Comment: Okay...how should it be structured then? Because I first need data from the axios GET call before the GET to the root directory of the website.

Comment: I think you mean that you need to hydrate your server's data from a REST call before you can render data to the client? Do you need to do that (a) only once on startup, or in (b) response to each client request? If (b), can you cache the call result for some time?

Comment: It needs to be called only once on startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is as pseudocode. It's good to start your program with this level of logical structure, and then implement it:

- Define ready = false, errored = false, and data = undefined
  variables.
- Get the data from the remote API, in the then branch, set
  ready = true, assign result to data. In the error branch, set errored
  = true. Should we retry on error?
- Define the / GET route.

  - If not ready, check errored. If not errored, we are still waiting for the data. In this case, do we wait for the call to resolve, or return something to the client to let them know?
  - If not ready, and errored, tell the client that there was an error.
  - If ready == true, then we have data to render a response to the client.
- Define the /down route. It needs to take a year parameter, and we need to make an async call in the route handler to get the data.

  - Can we cache the data, so that subsequent calls for the same year return data that we fetched previously? If we can, use an object as a lookup dictionary. If the object has a key for that year, use the cached data to render the response. If not, make the call, and in the then branch, add the response to the cache object, and use the data to render the response.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I've just been learning from a variety of resources and didn't know exactly how to structure it, but this clears up so much!